# Adobe Photoshop: Change text part color according to the background image color

Tags: background-image, photoshop, textcolor

Consider a background image that shows a white snowy mountain, yellow sky and blue sea. I'm writing a text content that passes through each of this, and the text color should change according to the background image color.

For instance, if I type SCENERY, and the 'S' part goes through the mountain, sky and sea, the color on the text should blend according to the color of the background image.

How do I create this effect in photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily do this in following steps

1) get your Mountain image on background layer.

2) get your text on upper layer.

3) change layer mode of text layer to value (you can experiment with different modes and text colors and see what works best).

Comment: Only a part of the text is over the mountain which should be in the same color. If the upper part of 'S' is over mountain it should be the same as "brown" color of mountain, the lower part of S over sea should be the same as "blue" color of sea.